# How do you correctly post data to the same view in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am having trouble getting the if statement in this Laravel view to work.

```
<h1>Login View</h1>

<form action="{{ route('type_of_user') }}"  method="post">
  <select name="type_of_user">
  <option value="Volunteer">Volunteer</option>
  <option value="Organization" selected>Organization</option>
   <br><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
  <input type="submit">
</select>
</form>


{{ $value }}
    <?php 
    if ($value = "Volunteer") {
        echo "I am a Volunteer";
    }
    else {
        echo "I am a Organization";
    }
```

The "{{ $value }}" is outputting the correct type of user when It is changed and submitted from the form. but the output of the if statement is not working at all correctly.  When Volunteer is selected the output is:

Volunteer I am a Volunteer

but when I select organization the output is:

Organization I am a Volunteer.

I first tired using the @if command in blade and got the same error.  I switched to PHP to see if the problem could have lied within my blade command, but got the same problem I am receiving with php.  The only thing I can think of is that maybe I am causing an error by submitting to the same page.

My controller for this code is:

```
class Usercontroller extends Controller
{
    public function Type_of_user(Request $request)
    {
        $value = $request['type_of_user'];


        return view('/login')->with('value', $value);
    } 
}
```

Any advice as to how to get the "if" statement to work correctly to what is selected is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not making a comparision you are making an assignment. Use double `=` sign.
`($value == "Volunteer")`

Comment: I could have sworn I tried this last night.  It is working great now.  Thanks for your help!